# Value stored in a variable in an event handler is null later on, why?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

In my code I write the value from `DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text` to `Label1.Text` and into `uploadFolder` in the `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` method. When the `ASPxUploadControl1_FileUploadComplete` method is called, the value is in `Label1.Text` but not in `uploadFolder`, which is null. Why is this?

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            Label1.Text = "You selected " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
            uploadFolder = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
    }

    protected void ASPxUploadControl1_FileUploadComplete(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsValid)
        {
            string uploadDirectory = Server.MapPath("~/files/");
            //string uploadDirectory = @"\\DOCSD9F1\TECHDOCS\";

            string fileName = e.UploadedFile.FileName;

            string path = (uploadDirectory + uploadFolder + "/" + fileName);
            //string path = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(uploadDirectory, uploadFolder), fileName);

            e.UploadedFile.SaveAs(path);
            e.CallbackData = fileName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: are they any `UpdatePanel`s involved ?

Comment: UploadFolder is just a field or property on your form class?

Comment: Where is `uploadFolder` defined?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `uploadFolder` is a variable you've declared on your page, something like this:

```
public class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string uploadFile = null;

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your code here
    }

    protected void ASPxUploadControl1_FileUploadComplete(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

What's happening is that the content of `uploadFile` that you're setting in `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` isn't being preserved between post-backs, because it isn't a property of one of the controls on the page. You need to store the value somewhere that gets persisted, such as the [View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) or in [Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx).

To do this, you should add to the `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` method so it reads something like:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        Label1.Text = "You selected " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        Session["UploadFolder] = DropoDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
}
```

And adjust the `ASPxUploadControl1_FileUploadComplete` method so it extracts `uploadFolder from the Session:

```
string path = (uploadDirectory + Session["UploadFolder"] + "/" + fileName);
```

---

If you want to make it look more elegant than that, consider using ViewState in this sort of way:

```
public string UploadFolder
{
    get
    {
        return (string)ViewState["UploadFolder"];
    }
    set
    {
      ViewState["UploadFolder"] = value;
    }
}
```

You can then do this:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        Label1.Text = "You selected " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        UploadFolder = DropoDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
}
```

And:

```
string path = (uploadDirectory + UploadFolder + "/" + fileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that you are not persisting `uploadFolder` through page post backs. Store the value in a hidden field, e.g.:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidden_UploadFolder" runat="server" />
```

And then:

```
hidden_UploadFolder.Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
```

You can then read it again on the next post back:

```
string uploadFolder = hidden_UploadFolder.Value;
```

Make sure you add error trapping.

Comment: I tried this solution, but uploadfolder still takes in no value... why would the label1 take the value fine but uploadfolder will not?

Comment: local server side page variables like your uploadfolder will not be saved during round trips to the server. The label keeps the value because of the .net viewstate. uploadfolder is not included in viewstate.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are setting the value for upload folder in one postback and using it in another. If you want to persist data between postbacks use the Session.

ex.

```
Session["uploadFolder"] = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;

string path = (uploadDirectory + Session["uploadFolder"].ToString() + "/" + fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            Label1.Text = "You selected " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
            Session["uploadFolder"] = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
    }

    protected void ASPxUploadControl1_FileUploadComplete(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsValid)
        {
            string uploadDirectory = Server.MapPath("~/files/");
            //string uploadDirectory = @"\\DOCSD9F1\TECHDOCS\";

            string fileName = e.UploadedFile.FileName;
            string uploadfolder = Session["uploadFolder"] as String;
            string path = (uploadDirectory + uploadfolder + "/" + fileName);
            //string path = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(uploadDirectory, uploadFolder), fileName);

            e.UploadedFile.SaveAs(path);
            e.CallbackData = fileName;
        }
    }
```